# How can I identify a guest user for a time longer than session usually exists

Tags: php, laravel, session

I know, that I can use `\Session::getId()`. But it changes form time to time. Maybe I do not understand the sessions. As I know it starts when php runs and it is deleted when php code is finished. On the other hand I read that session id is stored in cookie and when a user open your site again, the session 'restores'. So why in my case the session id expires so quickly. How can I get the 'session id' that does not change at least for a month and that is used by shopping carts?

**Update:** The question becomes a little confusing because I do not want how call some things and do not know how these things work.

I want to know how I can identify a guest user and get its unique id for some period of time (longer than sessions usually exist). In the result I want to have function `someFunction` which could do the following:

```
$guestId = someFunction();
$dbRow = Model::findByGuestIdOrNew($guestId);
// now $dbRow contains all previosly save info about a guest user, 
// of it does not exists, create new row by `$guestId`.
```

It seems to me that there is some unique id of session, which exists for time longer than session. This thought came to me when I've seen that in most cart packages cart items are saved directly to session. I really do not know how long these packages store cart items, but I think this time is even longer than a week. This period of time for lifetime of cart was defined by me while working with such shopping platforms: [shopify](https://www.shopify.com/) and [bigcommerce](http://bigcommerce.com/). I know they store cart item longer than a week. So I want to know how they identify a guest user before he creates an account. Also It will be a useful information to know how long most 'shopping cart' packages store cart items.

Comment: imo, Please be aware 'sessions' are for 'temporary data with a lifetime of about 30 minutes' . Another way of thinking about them : They are server side data linked to a 'client side cookie' and looked after by PHP. There is nothing preventing you from linking your own server side data linked with 'your client side cookie' - looked after by only you. (see 'remember me cookie) :) This is how you get 'you data to last for a long time' - don't fight PHP sessions,

Comment: so, "long" sessions completely depends on cookie? If I delete cookie from my browser, I delete session?

Comment: imo, You got it. That is exactly how it works. Actually - you don't delete the session - you lose the link to it. Please leave PHP to look after sessions and you look after stuff that you want to link to longer term. For example - shopping carts - link them to the user - not the session. when the user logs in they get the shopping cart?

Comment: @RyanVincent I do not want to allow carts only for registered user but for guests as well. If the user was logged in I would use userId. And get cart by this userId. But how can I replace userId if a user is just a guest?

Comment: I have just started shopping at an 'online supermarket' . When I next login in a few days time 0 I can contiue shopping with the same basket. They don't keep PHP sessions for days. It will occupy 'rather a lot of temporary data',. The shopping cart is linked to my user.

Comment: @RyanVincent how allow having cart for guests?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97030/discussion-between-freelightman-and-ryan-vincent).

Comment: A guest has to login to pay for the stuff in the cart. Send them a cookie that has a 'unique' 'guest id', create a 'guest user with that id'. When they login or want to pay - link them all up? Delete 'guests'  if they don't return after a few hours? Note - I am not interested in PHP sessions.

Comment: @RyanVincent of course a guest have to login to make an order. But we are talking about the cart only. A lot of ecommerce engine allow having carts without having an account. Sorry, but I do not understand "Send them a cookie that has a 'unique' 'guest id' "

Comment: @RyanVincent `$response->withCookie(cookie()->forever('shopping_cart', 'true'));` ?

Comment: We are not talking about a cart only! we are talking about a cart with a 'client http session'! For that you need a cookie that has a unique id in it. That way you can link the client request with the correct cart? The only communication is the cookie?

Comment: @FreeLightman when you use an ecommerce website without logging in and put something into the shopping cart, if you come back to that website after a month do you expect the contents to be still there? If that website doesn't store the cart contents directly in a cookie you'll most likely be disappointed. And it just feels like overkill to keep the cart for such a long time, for a guest user that might never return to the website.

Comment: @RyanVincent you are right. mayby a month is too long. however, this issue is off-topic. I understood how to connect a guest to the cart in DB. It revealed that I do not need session id at all. Complicated things became easy ones. Thank you for helping!

Comment: Thanks for listening to me - was good to get my view expressed.

Answer (score 6):

Laravel implements a custom way of handling sessions, but the logic is the same as the one described by the [PHP Sessions Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php). Here's an excerpt from that documentation that pretty much explains the logic behind it:

> Sessions are a simple way to store data for individual users against a unique session ID. This can be used to persist state information between page requests. Session IDs are normally sent to the browser via session cookies and the ID is used to retrieve existing session data. The absence of an ID or session cookie lets PHP know to create a new session, and generate a new session ID.

So your understanding of how sessions use IDs is right, but there is a another component to sessions that defines how long they last. Sessions expire after a predefined period of time, which in the case of Laravel, can be set in the `config/session.php` file:

```
'lifetime' => 120,
```

The above default value means that the session will expire after 120 minutes of inactivity from the user. There is also the option to expire the session when the user closes the browser, thus forcing a new session to be generated when he opens the browser again, by setting:

```
'expire_on_close' => true,
```

You should read the [Laravel Sessions Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session) for more insight into how Laravel handles sessions, and also read the comments from the `config/session.php` file which explain what each configuration option does and what values it can take.

---

The above explained how sessions work in PHP and Laravel, so in your case to make the session last for a whole month you could set the `lifetime` value to:

```
'lifetime' => 60*24*30 // 60 minutes x 24 hours x 30 days = 43200 minutes
```

But that seems like a really long time to keep a session, especially if the session also contains authentication info. If you want to persist the contents of a shopping cart I suggest you store them in the database and when the user logs in the next time just populate the session from the database.

---

For example the [Cartalyst Cart](https://cartalyst.com/manual/cart/2.0#cart-sync) library (which happens to have really nice Laravel integration) handles all the logic behind a shopping cart, while offering a nice [`sync`](https://cartalyst.com/manual/cart/2.0#cart-sync) method that allows you to add the cart items stored in the database to your current session. You could do the following to restore a cart from the database:

```
// Get the items from the database
$items = CartItem::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();

// Sync the items with the session cart
Cart::sync($items);
```

The above assumes you have a `cart_items` table that has a `CartItem` model attached, and that you're using the [Laravel Authentication](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication) to handle users sessions, but as you can see it leads to a very easy to implement solution.

Comment: My real goal is to get session id that does not expire for a long time. I want to use it as identifier for cart (I will store them in db). I really do not want to change laravel session lifetime, as I am not going to use sesstion now. I searched for how shopping cart packages define user, but I only saw that cart was directly saved to session. It seems that I understand how sesstion works but I cannot solve my problem

Comment: But how Cartalyst Cart identify the user? I do not understand this.

Comment: Cartalyst doesn't need to identify the user, it only needs to receive the items that need to be stored in the current session shopping cart, that's why I specified that the user session handling is done via the [Laravel Authentication](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication) system. It's your responsibility to handle adding cart items to the database.

Comment: I am not going to use Cartalyst or any other cart package. I want get the identifer, by which I can save cart in db. In the result I want: `$id = getSomeId(); $cart  = CartModel::where('session_id', $id')`.

Comment: That's your choice, I didn't say you should use Cartalyst, it was just an example. But in my opinion that `$id` should be your a user ID not a session ID, because the session ID is not a reliable way to identify the persisted data over a long period of time. Just take into consideration the very good point made by @RyanVincent in his comment.

Comment: @Bogdan If session ID is not reliable, then why does Cartalyst store cart in session? If user logs in, the session is regenerated and you lose the session id reference to your anonymous cart. At the same time, you can't store `user_id` because guest users don't have accounts. Can you elaborate on how Cartalyst solves these issues?