# Identifying and persisting guest users in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I am building an online store website as a side project with Laravel 5.3. My goal is to implement anonymous *and* authenticated shopping. Here are the `Customer`, `Cart`, and `CartItem` tables so far:

```
// (1) customers table...
table->increments('id');
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned(); // -> User hasOne('App\Customer') rel.
$table->string('first_name');
// last_name, dob, phone, etc. + timestamps

// (2) carts table...
$table->increments('id');
// -> Customer identification (and not user_id, because admins don't have carts!):
$table->integer('customer_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
// -> Guest identification:
$table->string('session_id');
$table->timestamps();

// (3) cart_items table...
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('cart_id')->unsigned();
$table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
$table->integer('quantity')->unsigned();
$table->timestamps();
```

However, I am not sure how to identify guest users and bind them with carts. The idea is, if you shop as a guest and then register or log in, your cart should become authenticated, i.e. I need to do `$cart->customer_id = Auth::user()->customer->id`. But how do I bind guests with their anonymous carts (i.e. when `$cart->customer_id == null`)?

#### Approaches

- If I store `Session::getId();` in `$cart->session_id` whenever a new `Cart` is created, then I am at **risk**, because session id in Laravel is **regenerated** quite frequently (e.g. [during login authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#regenerating-the-session-id)). So, if a guest logs in, I can no longer find their cart `Cart::where('session_id', Session::getId())` because their `Session` id has just been regenerated upon login!
- Another option would be to store a random string instead of `session_id`, e.g. write `$table->uuid('guest_id')` in `carts` migration. This token would be persisted in the database and in the client-side cookie (as suggested by Snapey in a [similar question on Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/identify-guest-for-bookmarked-posts?page=0)).
- Yet another option is to create a 'guest' `User`, possibly with a role of `guest`, but with no password or email. When customer decides to register, I could then populate those fields with the values from the registration form.

#### Considerations

The problem I see with cookies though is that they are less 'persistent', and I still feel that storing the cart (both anonymous and authenticated) in session is more secure. At the same time, I can't change session `lifetime` to e.g. 30 days, since sessions also store authentication info and since this might simply be an overkill for the server. As for guest users, I would need to make `email` and `password` nullable in `users` table, which smells like a bad practice (*don't change code you don't own* type of thing).

#### Question

Are there any other approaches to solving this problem? What would be the best and most secure practice to identify guest users and bind them with their anonymous shopping carts? Lastly, if I were to use Laravel sessions, does it make sense to use `database` sessions or rather `file` sessions? Do I need any changes to my `customers`, `carts`, or `cart_items` tables?

P.S. I am aware that shopping cart packages for Laravel *do* exist, but so far I haven't found one that incorporates anonymous + authenticated shopping and/or integrates with `users` table.

Comment: I have no good answer for this but your second solution may be the r8 choice.

Comment: @Amit Thanks! I initially thought about sessions, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098981/how-can-i-identify-a-guest-user-for-a-time-longer-than-session-usually-exists#answer-34099137) completely changed my understanding. As I can see, cookies + DB persistence would be a good sauce (thought maybe not the best). Still waiting on other answers...

Answer (score -2):

Well I am facing the same issue but the best possible solution I m thinking of right now is to give the users a downloadable tracking number or something like that so that when they come back they can just input that code and I can authenticate the cart items based on that code